# Setting Line Breakpoints in Intellij 15.02 doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints

Since yesterday I'm on IntelliJ 15.02 and cannot set any line breakpoints any longer. Neither by clicking on the side bar, nor by "Run -> Toggle Line Breakpoint". Is that a Bug in IntelliJ? Or is there any way to disable / enable this feature? I appreciate any help.

Comment: What type of files are you editing?

Comment: I just updated to 15.02 and it works fine for me, just tried to debug.

Answer (score 13):

This seems to be an issue with the python plugin. I uninstalled the python plugin, and the line breakpoints were available again. Then I reinstalled the plugin and still everything is fine. I use the python plugin because I have Jython scripts that I call from the Java code.

Comment: thanks for sharing, I have the same issue after upgrading to 15.02

Comment: I was able to set breakpoints in Python but not in any other languages. Reinstalling the Python plugin fixed the issue.

Comment: Saw this problem in my Java projects immediately after upgrading to 15.02.  For reference, I also run PyCharm.  Disabling the python plugin in IntelliJ made the problem go away.  Haven't tried re-enabling it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me but I did not have the Python plugin installed.

I tried (**with no success**):

- Rebuilding the project
- Invalidating caches
- Restarting IntelliJ
- Re-installing IntelliJ

**Fortunately, disabling the PHP plugin did the trick for me.**

Hope this helps someone.

**EDIT (Feb. 2nd, 2016)** This issue was fixed in IntelliJ 15.0.3: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-151085